# Quotes on a new page using \quotchap?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, double-sided, quotchap

I am trying to use `\quotchap` to put some text before the chapter title using

```
\begin{savequote}

The Quote 

\qauthor{Quote Author}

\end{savequote}
```

What I wanted was to put all the text on a page before the chapter and begin the chapter on a new page. The quote and the chapter should be on facing pages. This is required as in some cases there is a lot of text which I want to put. But when there is a lot of text, this text gets overlayed with chapter title and chapter text and the result is awful. Giving `\newpage` after the `savequote` environment does not help. It can be done manually, without using any special environment, it works in some cases. But I would really like to know if it can be done with `\quotchap`.

---

I am using `\documentclass{book}` with `twoside` format. Yes that should always be the case, each chapter is preceded by a quote.

---

When I compile the code in [Yiannis' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42362/5764), I get two chapters, one with and one without number. But I did not see the `\aquote` that you have defined and make reference to in the code. Do I have to add anything to the code above, am I missing something that needs to be done? When I try to put the `\savequote` before the chapter starts, it is showing up the quote text overlayed on chapter title and not on another page.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? I assume you're using a `twoside` document format, since you mention "facing pages". Also, would this *always* be the case? That is, quote on an even (verso) page and chapter start on an odd (recto) page?

Comment: @Werner: There are multiple versions of `\documentclass`? I only know that one! Works very well with all classes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a very good idea with one caveat to apply it only if the previous page is a blank page. This solves the problem (which I hate of a blank page, with a note *this is a blank page*) Here is some code to get you going where we cater both for the star version of the command as well as the normal version. I have used a small macro for the quote to keep the code to a minimal a focus on what needs to be changed. It should work equally well with 
the `quotchap` or `epigraph` packages.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\aquote{The real voyage of discovery consists not in seeking new landscapes but in having new eyes.
---Marcel Proust}
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\position{\centering}
%% Note the difference between the commands the one is 
%% make and the other one is makes
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \ifodd\thepage \else \clearpage \aquote \fi
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
        {\Huge \scshape  \thechapter }
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        {\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrule
    \vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}

%% This uses makes

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
   \ifodd\thepage \else \clearpage \aquote \fi
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
        {\Huge \scshape \vphantom{\thechapter}}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        {\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrule
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The Real Numbers}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter*{The Imaginary Numbers}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

If this works for you post a comment and I will amend the code to suit the package.